# How do I get Entity to populate the values of foreign key objects at the controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, data-binding

I'm attempting to use DataBinding in MSMVC using CodeFirst and the Entity Framework.  I'm trying to pass a model with a foreign key to the view, edit the data and bind the result back in a controller action before performing an update.

Simply put how do I get Entity to populate the values of foreign key objects at the controller.

The model is very simple and contains only a string 'Text' and the foreign key UserModel 'User'.  The BaseModel contains only an Id and a DateTime.

```
public class CommentModel : BaseModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual UserModel User { get; set; }
}
```

In my Razor view I have a hidden field for the User.Id :

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.User.Id)
```

In my controller action I have  :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(CommentModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    _commentsRepository.Update(model);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The problem is that ModelState contains errors as only the Id property of the UserModel is populated?

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have other properties being set via form fields in your view or are you simply passing the ID of the User back for some other reason.

If you are updating other properties of your UserModel in the view then these should be serialized via model binding automatically as long as the naming convention is correct "i.e. ID="User.Id" or ID="User.FirstName"...

Comment: Ahhhh.  I was under the impression I had to add the Id of the UserModel if I wanted it to bind.  If I told you how long I spent on this.  All I needed to do was remove the User.Id from the view :(.  Thanks for your time.